# I need a unknown amount of coordinates field (or few fields) How to go about doing this?

Tags: php, mysql, mapping, coordinates, dijkstra

Using MySQL I need to have a list (possibly long list) of x,y coordinates. How should I go about this?

Apologies for the amazing amount of vague in this question! I didn't want to explain my entire project but I suppose some more explanation is in order for this to make *any* sense as a question.

Ok I'm doing a a map/direction web application for a client (no, I've looked into Google Maps API, but I need to map their buildings/campus so I don't think that applies well). So my current plan is to create some PHP scripts that will run through dijkstra's algorithm (I'm purposely dumbing this down quite a bit because, again, I don't want to explain the whole project) but since that algorithm is based on the use of a graph I was going to have an Edge table that will contain various Coords so that I know, in the image, how to draw my lines. Does this make any more sense to you guys now? Again I apologize, I should've gone a little more into my issue originally.

Comment: What does, or could, your data look like?

Comment: I assume that there is more to your question than just "create a table with two fields".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Alright well I'm thinking of doing my own mapping/direction web application thing. I won't go too into the details of the whole project, but long story short for each edge in my graph of Dijkstra's Algorithm I need to store some coordinates so that I have something of pivot-points for the lines I'll be drawing across my map image. So no I'm not creating a table with two fields, this is a small part of my problem but I didn't want to pose my entire project as a problem haha, sorry if it sounded sort of vague.

Comment: I added some better description, I think these answers answer my question, but maybe you guys have more input considering my updated context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making a lot of assumptions since your question is vague...

Use two tables with a foreign key, this is the standard approach to model a one to many relationship

```
create table table1 (
id int
--more columns presumably
)
create table coordinates (
id int,
table_id int --foreign key with table1,
x int,
y int
)
```

Comment: I apologize, I added some more context to the problem, but your answer should work with my issue, it was getting later here when I wrote this so its possible my brain was just functioning less and less haha. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a database which, stores data. You can create a table with XCoord and YXoord fields which can handle millions of rows with ease.

```
CREATE TABLE Coordinates( id int(11) NOT NULL Auto_increment,
  X double NOT NULL,
  Y double NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```